# Flutter clippath over appbar

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

Hi Im having problem with clippath, Im trying to do a clippath like in the inserted image link [https://imgur.com/qDspPgV]. However, I realised I cant actually do this in flutter because appbar is block the way so it gives me a white space.

Is there a way where I could overlap it?

This is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
  runApp(LoginUI());
}

class LoginUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginUIState createState() => _LoginUIState();
}

class _LoginUIState extends State<LoginUI> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ClipPath(
                clipper: MyClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                )));
      })),
    ));
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * .5);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is my design output because of appbar
[https://imgur.com/UaKFvBO]
the clippath on the design is a placeholder. I havent decided to change it yet until I actually manage to overlap the appbar.

Edit: suggestion upon without appbar [https://imgur.com/93O1kX7], it doesnt go thoroughly on the status bar.

Edit: Thanks Albert [ https://imgur.com/5QsztCr ].

Comment: You can achieve what you want just by omitting the `appBar` `Scaffold` parameter and passing this clipped container at the top of a `Column` that you would have in your `Scaffold`'s `body`.

Comment: Hi Albert, i did that too and I added your suggestion in the edit. However, the status bar is not affected with it. Is there perhaps a way that the status bar could be reached out too?

Comment: That's because you used `SafeArea`. It does exactly that :)

Comment: Hi Albert check another edit and its photo! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want just by omitting the `appBar` `Scaffold` parameter and passing this clipped container at the top of a `Column` that you would have in your `Scaffold`'s `body`.

Also remember that `SafeArea` paddings out from the status bar among other things.